# Gradle Task with with command is not executed on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle

I have a project and I already create a function and a task in order to get some git information:

```
def git(command) {
    def gitCommandResult = "Unknown git information"
    try {
        def workingDir = new File("$rootDir/.git/")
        def result = command.execute(null, workingDir)
        result.waitFor()
        if (result.exitValue() == 0) {
            gitCommandResult = result.text.trim()
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error('Unable to reach information through Git command')
    }
    return gitCommandResult
```

After that I am setting the information as a System variable like this:

```
task getGitInformation {
    System.setProperty("GIT_BRANCH", git('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'))
}
```

And I am calling the task: getGitInformation into another task using a DependsOn.
When I run that locally all the data I need is getting. However, when running that on Jenkins I always getting "Unknown git information".
Jenkins has already installed the git plugin and I am not sure about why Jenkins can't reach the execution of the commands. Also, I am not getting an error in the console.

Do you think you can help me with this?

Comment: which is the exception thrown in the try/catch block?